# How to disable the add blocker?

Tags: updates

There are some websites I want to play on and I cant play on them because of the add blocker so how do i disable it for a while?

Answer (score 2):

To disable ad-blocking in eOS, you need to open the browser, click on the gear icon, and set the preferences to allow ads.

However, this isn't the kind of fidelity that you're looking for. In Epiphany, the eOS default browser, ad-blocking is binary, meaning that it is either on or it is off. You can't disable it for individual sites while keeping it enabled for other sites.

Your most realistic solution is to install another mainstream browser, such as [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) or [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/index.html). Then, install an ad-blocking extension - such as uBlock Origin. With that extension, you can visit the site, click on the extension in the browser's notification area, and disable ad-blocking for individual sites.

There are other browsers (such as [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/), [Brave](https://brave.com/), or [Opera](https://www.opera.com/)) that have built-in ad-blocking. In each of those cases, you also have the fidelity to disable blocking on a per-site basis.